# Is it possible to retrieve schedule data from Autodesk Forge?

Tags: c#, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

Currently we are exploring the possibilities of Autodesk Forge. 
We already implemented the Autodesk Forge Viewer and that's working fine, we would now like to extract schedule data from the Revit files we uploaded to Forge.

We have already seen some examples from the Autodesk blog where an Excel file is created from the viewer, but we are looking for a way to extract schedule data from an uploaded model preferably through an REST endpoint.

In the documentation we see a lot of examples te read metadata and geometry data but not schedule data. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Regards,

Comment: In the meantime I have found this.
This (https://extract.autodesk.io/) website is a showcase for retrieving data from Forge. I inspected the results but the data I am looking for is not available. The schedule metadata is, for example fields, filtering and grouping. But the actual data is missing.
[link](https://extract.autodesk.io/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Model Derivative API](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/job-POST/) extracts metadata from the visible elements on the model, in this case the properties you see on the Revit Property Panel. A few other properties are also extracted. Unfortunately, the schedules tables are not extracted yet.

Comment: Ok, do you know if it is possible through the Forge Viewer?

Comment: Do you know if adding this functionality is on the roadmap of Forge? And if so, on what term?